Normalize the close series data by today's close value
The following code will plot the close series data:
plot(close)

However, I want to normalize the close series by today's close value:
// If the today's (latest) close is 165, we will divide the close series by 165.
plot(close/165)

This will give us a normalized series where the latest normalized value will be 1, and we can compare different securities together (forward comparison).
The latest close varies every day. How could I normalize the close series by today's close value?
The following code is not correct:
// close[0] mean the close data on the drawing bar, not today's close (latest close)
plot(close/close[0])

Additional question
What if I want to normalized the series by a specific date?
For example, I want to normalized the series by the first date of every year.

Lets be honest:
The fact that you can't even bring up your question (and logic behind it) in at least pseudo code make me feel that you did not even spent 5 minutes on the Pine Script Manual or Reference Documentation. The brutal truth: You will not get anywhere without investing some time to study the most minimal basics yourself.
In an attempt still trying to be of help:

Prior plotting you should create a variable to store whatever value you want to further manipulate or plot. Example...

var float day_close = na


Next you need some logic to do whatever you want to do. Here is the catch: I got no idea what that is. At least TRY giving your question a meaning by e.g. using Pseudo Code.

When the daily candle closes: store the value of that price
As there is a new daily candle close & it has been stored, devide the result  by itself.
Plot the normalized value as line to chart.

With just this you'd be getting clarity about your needs and with 5 minute research/reading you already will find countless code examples.

Since you then want to do some calculations it'll be a good thing to define it.

var float result = na
if not na(day_close)
    result := day_close/day_close

Then you go and plot the result or do with it whatever you need.
For the addtional question:
You have been here for so long & by now should know that its rising chances to get a response of the question makes sense at all and by asking one question at a time == not sending a catalog here to outsource your responsibillity to at least read the manual first (which holds hundreds of examples)
